# Setting policy for including CDN file types to public CDN does nothing

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, public-cdn

I have been trying to set the public policy from the default public CDN "*/CLIENTSIDEASSETS" to include JSON file type. I can run the command from both PowerShell and the MS365 CLI but it seems to do nothing. As you can see, I have the files set it has been a few days:

[image]

But if I go to SharePoint and try to fetch a JSON file from the CLIENTSIDEASSETS, it just gives me 403. I did not find any other information for why this could be happening.

[image]

Fetching directly from the CLIENTSIDEASSETS without the public CDN works fine. But I wanted that to be available from the CDN by default. And by the way, I am calling this from the console but directly from the SharePoint site. So it is not a request from outside of SPO.

Does anyone know what I could have been missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ricardo:
Although I have never come across this particular issue before, given the description of what Microsoft considers ‘CDN worthy’ materiel, a .JSON file may not meet the requirement.   See here:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/use-microsoft-365-cdn-with-spo?view=o365-worldwide#CDNAssets
The documentation does not specifically *exclude* .JSON files, but does fundamentally focus on binary files.

A couple of ideas to troubleshoot:

1. rename the files to .TXT and change any code that’s reading them to parse those .TXT files as json content.  I don’t know how feasible this is for you.

And

2. Even though you are using the Public CDN, attempt the same configuration on the Private CDN and see if it will serve up you .JSON files.

If this answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: I mean, I know that works but it is exactly the type of workaround I am trying to avoid. Cause we already did that before. Problem is if there are those limitations then the docs should not just say we can add other file types cause it seems we can't.

Comment: I agree with you.  Documentation is ambiguous at best.  You now have a decision:
1.  use the above mentioned workaround and shape your code around it, or
2.  Create an Enterprise support ticket with Microsoft.  
2.a.:  if your company has a Microsoft certified solution provider or other Microsoft certified org - they can really accelerate the Ticket response process, since they likely have contacts within Microsoft that they can reach out to directly.

Comment: That is a fair point. Since this is something that we are already doing, renaming the json files to txt, or renaming them to js and adding 'export default' in front of it (and busting cache via code when needed). I will accept your answer.